# How to improve performance using spatial indexing with STIntersects()

Tags: sql-server, spatial-database

I am working on Spatial database. I need to check intersection of state geometry with geometry inside database. I am presently using the query as:

```
SELECT 
    a.ID, 
    a.OBJECTID,
    a.MSID, 
    a.FACNAME,
    Convert(varchar(max),a.ShapeGeo),
    b.State_Name 
FROM 
    XFAcilityBackUp26June a with(index(testIndexSpatial)),
    us_stateTest b      
WHERE 
    a.shapegeo.STIntersects(b.the_geom.MakeValid()) = 1 and b.State_Name = 'Texas'
```

It is functioning properly but it takes more time(more than 10 minutes) to execute. I have tried indexing also but no luck with it.

Is there any alternative way to improve the performance?

Comment: Why would you MakeValid with every query?  Is your attribute constraint more restrictive than the spatial? (If so, it should be first in the WHERE clause).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If i am not write that MakeValid() than some times it gives me error.

Comment: You should *permanently*  repair table contents before attempting to use it in performance evaluation.

Comment: Please edit the question to provide vital information about the tables: Number of rows in each table, Number of rows in each table which meet the WHERE constraints (separately, and in conjunction), How long it takes to perform a full table scan on each table, What index options you used to create the testIndexSpatial index (and on which table it is created)